# Change the label of an input field based on dropdown list

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update the text label on an input field based on the selection in a dropdown list.

The field label below by default reads "Mean." I'd like it to be replaced by "Lower bound" if option 2 is selected.

```
<simpleLabel for="distLabel">Prior distribution, <i>CFR</i>:</label>
<select id="priorCFRDistType" onchange='changePriorDistType();'>
<option value="1">beta</option>
<option value="2">uniform</option>
</select>
<p>
<simpleLabel for="cfr_1">Mean:</label>
<input id="cfr_1" type="text" value ="0.05" />
```

In my `.js` file, I have `changePriorDistType()`. It currently does a lot of stuff under the hood. How do I get it to update the text field? This is what I've tried so far:

```
function changePriorDistType() {
    menuItem = document.getElementById("priorCFRDistType");
    priorCFRDistType = menuItem.options[menuItem.selectedIndex].value;
    if ( priorCFRDistType == 2 ) {
       var tmpThing = document.getElementById("cfr_1").innerText;
       tmpThing = "Lower bound";
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I'm clearly new to Javascript and HTML, so nothing's too obvious to point out. Thanks.

Comment: simpleLabel is a valid tag?

Comment: I am not sure where I would check that. (I am editing someone else's code.) Where would it be declared/defined? I'm not seeing it in the css.

Comment: Ok, that was a hint, it's not a valid tag.

Comment: Sorry--it was added by a much more skilled developer and has been in the code for ages, though we haven't needed to update labels until now. Are you saying this should work if I update all with `label`?

Comment: Yes. The opening tag must match the closing tag. They may have hacked-around their own mistakes, so who knows what will happen when you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first mistake (beside that mismatching tags) is that with `getElementById("cfr_1")` you get the element with the id `cfr_1` which is the `input` element not the label.

second error is that, with `tmpThing = "Lower bound"` you won't change the innerText of the element. you need to do e.g. `document.getElementById('cfr_1_label').innerText = "Lower bound"` (but that would require you to add the id `cfr_1_label` to the `label` tag)

Comment: Got it. With `<label for="cfr_1_lbl">Mean:</label>
` in the html and `document.getElementById('cfr_1_lbl').innerText = "Lower bound";` in the js function, I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null"

Comment: @neophyte are you sure you did it right ? it should look like this: `<label for="cfr_1" id="cfr_1_lbl">Mean:</label>` the message `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null"` tells you that `getElementById` returned null (no element with that id was found)

Comment: Woohoo! I had missed the `id=...`